# Updating in mongodb using java

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

i m using put method as 
basicobj.put("1",obj.setAddre()+obj1.setFName());
while updating i want to update only the address but here the enitre value is updating.Value for key "1" is updating. is there any method or give me hint to update only the address.
Here is my code...

```
public class AccessObjectID{
public static void main(String[] args)throws UnknownHostException {

    AccessObject obj1 = new AccessObject();
    obj1.setAddre("Sector No:-42,Los Angeles,USA");
    obj1.setFirstName("Jack");
    obj1.setLName("Reacher");
    obj1.setEmail("Jack_reacher@myid.com");
    obj1.setPNumber("02024568963");

    AccessObject obj2 = new AccessObject();
    obj2.setAddre(",USA");
    obj2.setFirstName("udsy ");
    obj2.setLName("jhkjhkjad");
    obj2.setEmail("aisisior@myid.com");
    obj2.setPNumber("02024568963");

    MongoClient mongoclient = new MongoClient("localhost",27017);
    DB dbobj = mongoclient.getDB("demo");
    DBCollection colc = dbobj.getCollection("demo_1");
    BasicDBObject basicdbobj = new BasicDBObject();

    colc.remove(basicdbobj);

    basicdbobj.put("1", obj1.getAddress()
                        +obj1.getFName()
                        +obj1.getLName()
                        +obj1.getEmail()
                        +obj1.getPNumber());

    basicdbobj.put("2", obj2.getAddress()
                        +obj2.getFName()
                        +obj2.getLName()
                        +obj2.getEmail()
                        +obj2.getPNumber());

    colc.insert(basicdbobj);

    DBCursor db =  colc.find();

    while(db.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(db.next());
    }


    System.out.println("********************************** \n"+"UPDATE");
    obj1.setAddre("Pune,India");

    BasicDBObject update = new BasicDBObject();
    update.put("1",obj1.getAddress());

    BasicDBObject updateobj = new BasicDBObject();
    updateobj.put("$set",update);//new BasicDBObject().append("",""));//update);

    colc.update(basicdbobj, updateobj);

    db = colc.find();
    while(db.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(db.next());
    }

    colc.save(basicdbobj);
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understood, you are looking to replace the address value of a document which has the address value "Pune,India". If that's the case try the following:

```
BasicDBObject newDocument = new BasicDBObject();
newDocument.append("$set", new BasicDBObject().append("1", "New Address"));

BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject().append("1", "Pune,India");

colc.update(searchQuery, newDocument);
```

Comment: Sector No:-42,Los Angeles,USA this  address i want to update but problem is against "1" key i m having the entire value i,e;output looks like this    :-{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "55891e47c018ab3d78ebeb28"} , "1" : "Sector No:-42,Los Angeles,USAJackReacherJack_reacher@myid.com02024568963"           when i update the entire thing gets updated but i want only the address to be updated not the reset thing